# Как часто можно голосовать за переоткрытие вопроса?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, переоткрытие-вопросов

Думал, что за один вопрос можно голосовать только один раз, но наткнулся на вот такое сообщение:

> Вы уже проголосовали за повторное открытие этого вопроса. Голосование можно будет повторить 13 янв в 3:00

Так как часто можно голосовать за переоткрытие одного и того же вопроса?
Полагаю, с закрытием ситуация такая же?

Comment: А можно ссылку на вопрос, в котором такое сообщение?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, там есть ограничение - я на него натыкался при поптыке закрыть открытый кем-то вопрос. точно не помню, вроде в 30 дней.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477718/web-api-rest-php - теперь пишет через 9 дней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это зависит от судьбы предыдущего голоса.

Если голос за закрытие или переоткрытие привёл к желаемому результату (т.е., вопрос был закрыт или переоткрыт), то вновь проголосовать таким же образом невозможно.

Однако, у голосов за закрытие/переоткрытие есть "срок годности": если они не набираются в нужном количестве, то через некоторое время они пропадают. В этом случае можно проголосовать вновь, но только через 14 дней после пропадания предыдущего голоса. В принципе, это можно продолжать бесконечно, но на практике таких упорных мало.

Срок годности голосов: ориентировочно 14 дней, но может быть больше (если после него добавились другие голоса, отсчёт начинается вновь) или меньше (если вопрос прошёл через очередь проверки с вердиктом "оставить открытым/закрытым", срок годности выходит сразу). И ещё один момент: когда срок годности заканчивается, голоса удаляются не все сразу, а по одному в день.

Источник: [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223)